# Is there a word or term used to categorize words that are unnecessary to conform with grammar rules and don't add to the meaning of a sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In the following sentences, "that" is unnecessary:

> He claims **that** he was at the library yesterday.
>
> The professor believes **that** Terry Stops are practiced unconstitutionally by the police forces.

Is there a word or term used to categorize words that are unnecessary to conform with grammar rules and don't add to the meaning of a sentence?

Comment: Your title question and body question are not identical. The use of  'that' in your examples does not warrant 'you should get rid of it'. In general, words (or groups of words) being dropped without intentional change of meaning is a process known as 'deletion'. These are examples of _that_-deletion. As you will see if you look up relevant articles here, deletions can (quickly) lead to ambiguities.

Comment: The words aren't precisely unnecessary; they are just so common that they are understood. They are called deletions, and there are many kinds: "whiz deletions", "to be deletions", etc. This one is specifically called a "that deletion".

Comment: Many grammar books use an adjective such as **omissible** or **deletable** to describe such words.

Comment: "Stupid advice." It's not a good idea to get rid of *all* unnecessary words, and these *that*'s are perfectly fine as is.

Comment: @PeterShor I can't agree with you more.

Comment: @Peter Shor My questions doesn't state you should get rid of all unnecessary words.

Comment: Your question does or you had better edit the title.

Comment: It depends on whether you use and or so as the conjugation.  I understand the ambiguity.  I have made the appropriate edits.

Comment: In the computer techie environment, words that have no syntactic or semantic purpose are called "noise words". Words that are required by the syntax but carry no semantics are called "syntactic sugar".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A ***pleonasm*** is "the use of more words than are necessary to express an idea" ([here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pleonasm) and [here](http://changingminds.org/techniques/language/figures_speech/pleonasm.htm))

You gave examples involving the ***sentential complementizer*** 'that'. When occurring after a propositional attitude verb like 'claims' and 'believes', the word is entirely ***optional***. But it is a matter of style and preference whether or not you *should* get rid of it. Just because it is not necessary doesn't mean you should get rid of it.

Comment: Pleonasm is a stylistic flaw, redundancy. This is more asking for a grammatical term.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily a stylistic flaw. I've seen languages such as French which require the use of two particles to express negation ('ne' and 'pas') described as involving *pleonastic negation*. This is not a matter of style. It's a matter of syntax. The second particle 'pas' is not semantically necessary, much the same way 'that' is not necessary. There is, of course a disanalogy. 'pas' is redunant given 'ne', whereas 'that' is not redundant. In the sense that it is not redundant, you might object to calling 'that' pleonastic in such sentences.

Comment: My sincere apologies, then. I'll leave me comment, because your response is valuable.

Comment: I made an edit to your answer, one that mentions "syntactic pleonism" (Your comment prompted me to search for it.). If that's objectionable, please roll back!

Comment: A welcome addition! I never heard the expression, but there's actually a whole section of the 'pleonasm' Wikipedia entry devoted to it, using examples exactly like the original poster's!

Comment: (I saw that, but tend to shy away from Wiki entries on SE... I know their health related entries are often problematic, so I just don't reference them. Snobby, I know. But thank you for being so gracious.)

Comment: Wikipedia does seem a little self-contradictory with: 'to satisfy the syntactic requirement for an explicit subject a pleonastic (or dummy) pronoun is used; only the first sentence in the following pair is acceptable English:

"It rains."
"Rains." '  I'm not sure which flavour of 'pleonastic' they are using here, as an overheard fragment '... rains' is indeterminate (V or N?, for a start). I'd stick with 'Dummy it is non-deletable here'.

Comment: @medica by health do you mean anatomy/physiology or something else? (I depend a lot on the medication articles (not for taking them!))

Comment: @Mitch - I mean, anything related to health (like medications, diseases, etc.) I used to think Wikipedia was pretty valuable, but as I read their entries on health related matters more carefully now (I was doing so because of Wiki references in Health.SE answers), I discovered that the quality is really, really spotty, and only as good as the mind interpreting the sources, which are sometimes atrocious (sources and interpretations.) Since that and some other Biology stuff are my only fields of expertise, I can only comment on that (but wonder about other fields.)

Comment: @Mitch - and a btw - you might get a better answer on health-related questions on Health.SE than Wikipedia. Wikipedia as a source is strongly discouraged, so there's a higher standard for information.

Comment: @medica but that leaves the question, what is it you're calling health: "I have a runny nose and tingling in both pinkies, should I take vitamin D" or "the seventh cranial nerve is oculopharyngeal and exits the skull through the pons and switches sides". Biology is what I'm concerned with, not health advice. So is wikipedia bad on both?

Comment: @Mitch - Well... it's ok on anatomy (though falls short.) It doesn't address specific questions about health. On Biology topics in general, it's pretty helpful for beginners. Does that help? Otherwise I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[superfluous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/superfluous)*

> Unnecessary, especially through being more than enough:
>   *the purchaser should avoid asking for superfluous information*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Consider the examples given in the *[American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=superfluous)* entry for *superfluous*

> Synonyms: superfluous, excess, extra, supernumerary, surplus
>   These adjectives mean being more than is needed, desired, required, or appropriate: ***delete superfluous words***; trying to lose excess weight; found some extra change on the dresser; supernumerary ornamentation; distributed surplus food to the needy.

Answer (score 1):

There are options.

- [optional](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/optional). This is the most likely word to describe the situation formally.
- [facultative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/facultative) which means optional. This is a scientific term, used in many sciences, in opposition to [obligate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obligate) which means necessary. It is not used much in linguistics, but works.
- [pleonastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) is by definition, the use of more words than are necessary. This is most commonly used for content words like 'free gift' or 'repeat over and over'. It can be used to describe syntactic items but that doesn't say if one is allowed grammatically to remove the item. For example, in 'I am green', 'I' and 'am' are pleonastic, but neither can be removed.

So 'optional' is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me "that" you are mistaken.  That is acting as a subordinating conjunction.  These are two simple sentences.  He Claims. (what does he claim?) He was at the library yesterday.  "that" is absolutely necessary to tie the two sentences together, unless you speak broken english! 
http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/that-subordinating-conjunction-or-relative-pronoun.1337388/
 goody, goody gumdrops!

Comment: "Rasoul said he is confident the military will retake other cities captured by ISIS." CNN.com

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Did you read other answers and comments posted above? Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: 'that' is not absolutely necessary by grammar rules of almost all the varieties of Modern English that I am aware of, BUt certainly not necessary in GenAmE